# Suppress internal React Native propType validation

Tags: react-native

Using the CardStack from React Native NavigatorExperimental in version 0.27.2, I get the following PropType validation error:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `sceneRendererProps.isRequired`
```

It seems that this validation is wrong, however, because `isRequired` shouldn't be a prop. It's caused by calling `PropTypes.shape` twice.

This error is solved on React Native master, but is not yet in the release. How can I suppress the Yellow Box in the meantime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a small error in the proptype definition of SceneView in NavigationCard.js

It is already fixed ([commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/fb5d0ff587063dc5dec1985716375a9721e48c59)) in master, but that fix didn't make it into release 0.27.

**Workaround:** 
Add a specific ignore to hide the warning (it's harmless)

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `sceneRendererProps.isRequired`'];
```

**Solution:**
Upgrade to 0.28